# How to solve A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of call to mf:extract-year in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to solved "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of call to mf:extract-year" because my Input para in year one time and two times e.g. `(SD NY 1967) 268 F Supp 289, aff’d (2d Cir 1968)` after run last two entry's s/b not moved.
**Input**

```
<root>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">A.H. Emery Co. v Marcan Prods. Corp. (SD NY 1967) 268 F Supp 289, aff&#x2019;d (2d Cir 1968) 389 F2d 11:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">A.M. v Albertsons, LLC (2009) 178 CA4th 455:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ABBA Rubber Co. v Seaquist (1991) 235 CA3d 1:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2017) 2 C5th 1074:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2018) 2 C5th 1074:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (9th Cir 2017) 865 F3d 1261:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Frlekin v Apple, Inc. (9th Cir 2017) 870 F3d 867:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Frlekin v Apple, Inc. (review granted Sept. 20, 2017, S243805) 2017 Cal Lexis 7496:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Aug. 6, 2013, No. C 11&#x2013;04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 111502:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Jan. 4, 2013, No. C 11&#x2013;04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 1592:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:function name="mf:extract-year" as="xs:integer?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)([0-9]{4})\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 2]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-sort" as="xs:string?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 1]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="let $year := mf:extract-year(.)
                    return if ($year) then -$year else 1"/>
                <xsl:sort select="let $sort := mf:extract-sort(.)
                    return if ($sort) then $sort else 1" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output**

```
<root>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">A.H. Emery Co. v Marcan Prods. Corp. (SD NY 1967) 268 F Supp 289, aff’d (2d Cir 1968) 389 F2d 11:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">A.M. v Albertsons, LLC (2009) 178 CA4th 455:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">ABBA Rubber Co. v Seaquist (1991) 235 CA3d 1:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2018) 2 C5th 1074:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (9th Cir 2017) 865 F3d 1261:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2017) 2 C5th 1074:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Frlekin v Apple, Inc. (review granted Sept. 20, 2017, S243805) 2017 Cal Lexis 7496:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Frlekin v Apple, Inc. (9th Cir 2017) 870 F3d 867:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Aug. 6, 2013, No. C 11–04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 111502:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Jan. 4, 2013, No. C 11–04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 1592:</named-content>
   </p>
</root>
```

**CODE** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/7

Comment: Can the second year or substring inside `()` be ignored for sorting? Then use `*:match[1]` instead of `*:match`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Yes, We can ignore second year for sorting. Because we are sorting only 1st time inside ().

Comment: Check whether https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/8 gives you the wanted result, it ignores anything but the first match inisde `()`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Sequence is move good this function but last two entry's s/b not moved. These entry's already sorting "Bradford Technols., Inc. v NCV Software.com (ND Cal, Aug. 6, 2013, No. C 11–04621 EDL) 2013 US Dist Lexis 111502:" and . Is it possible? (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/11)

Comment: So for these two entries  you don't want to sort only by the year (e.g. `2013`) but by the complete date (e.g. `Aug. 6, 2013`)? I think in the long run you somehow might be better off to normalize the data in a first step by making sure you have the sort keys (e.g. year or complete date) for all entries in the same and full format. As with all previous problems, a precise implementation requires a precise requirement description, I guess `analyze-string` can also extract a date but only if we know the exact format and all possible omissions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Yes, sort only year (e.g. `2013`) not sort complete date (e.g. `Aug. 6, 2013`).

Comment: Does https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/12 work for you as intended? As I said, with all the variations of data you have in there and want to group based on substrings or regular expression patterns, I would suggest to normalize the data in some pre-processing, so that all grouping and sort keys have the same format, then the grouping and sorting of the normalized data would be straight-forward.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Accepted! Nice Code and nice output According to my Expected output. Thank you Martin Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what we established in the comments, the function to extract the year needs to be adapted to return only the first match with `*:match[1]` and for data in parenthesis where you also have a complete date we need to extract and use a further sort key:

```
<xsl:param name="months" as="xs:string*"
  select="'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'"/>

<xsl:param name="date-pattern" as="xs:string"
  select="'\((.*?)((' || string-join($months, '|') || ')\. ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})).*?\)'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-date" as="xs:date?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="let $match := analyze-string($input, $date-pattern)/*:match[1]
                return 
                if ($match) 
                then xs:date(
                        $match//*:group[@nr = 5] 
                        || '-' || format-integer(index-of($months, $match//*:group[@nr = 3]), '00') 
                        || '-' || format-integer($match//*:group[@nr = 4], '00'))
                else ()"/>
</xsl:function>


<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="let $year := mf:extract-year(.)
                    return if ($year) then -$year else 1"/>
                <xsl:sort select="let $date := mf:extract-date(.)
                    return if (exists($date)) then $date else 1" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="let $sort := mf:extract-sort(.)
                    return if ($sort) then $sort else 1" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/12

Comment: Sir, Can we ignore month function in complete date sorting only descending order type date and year only (e.g. `02`, `2013`) (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/15) last two lines s/b `SD Ind, Sept. 24, 2015` after `SD Ind, Oct. 1, 2015`?

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the function as

```
<xsl:function name="mf:extract-year" as="xs:integer?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)([0-9]{4})\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 2]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

This will fail if the analyze-string call finds more than one match (that is, if the input string contains more than one four-digit number in parentheses). So the way to prevent the error is to detect that there is more than one match and do something about it. I don't know what you want to do if there is more than one (relevant) year in the input data. You could, for example, choose the first, which would simply involve adding `[1]` to your expression.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the reply!